# how to show this one to many relation data in hierarchical order in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, one-to-many, laravel-blade

Need tips for displaying this one to many related data on a heirarchical 
   order in laravel view page. Here vegetable, groceries are category and 
   other's are there related product.
   [Here is the image for data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfqko.png)

```
Need to show this every 1 to many related data on a hierarchical order on 
a single view page. I want to loop through these array and 
want my result like tree view:
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: $stock = DB::table('categories')
            ->join('ingridients', 'ingridients.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->select('categories.category_name', 'categories.id', 'ing_name', 
             'available_wt', 'available_pcs')
            ->get();
this is my backend code and I have no idea on how should i loop through these data, as you can see on every array there is a category name itself. Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: Can you post your models??? We need to sho the relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your given information I will try to help you as much as possible.

Looking at your image, shows me that you already have duplicated data in your database. Where possible try to use different tables for different entities. In this case your Category is used over and over again. So try to create a new table for it.

That being said, you still have 2 options for this. A one to many or many to many relationship between your ingredient and category. This depends on what you want, do you want an ingredient to be able to have one or many categories. I have added a image below to show the 2 types of database structures for this. (Left: One to many, Right: Many to many)

[image]

You will have to create 2 models for both the Category and the Ingredient and make sure that you can use those models to store and receive data from your database. If you would like some more information about models take a look here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#defining-models

After creating your models, you should define your relation methods inside your models. This is different based on the choice you have made. (many to many or one to many).

One to many:

In the one to many example an ingredient can have only 1 category. Therefor you have to create a method in your ingredient called category and this should return a HasOne:

```
    /**
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function category(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::class);
    }
```

Then your category can have multiple Ingredients so your Category should get a method called ingredients and it must return a BelongsToMany:

```
    /**
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function ingredients(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class);
    }
```

Many to many:

In a many to many relation your category will be the same because it still has many ingredients. Only the ingredient will change because it not also has many categories. The method for the categories will now just be the same as the one for the ingredients:

```
    /**
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function categories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
```

That is that! Now how to use this (and hopefully the answer to your question). When you have a category like:

```
$category = Category::first();
```

You are able to use the ingredients method to get all the ingredients having this category:

```
$category = Category::first();
$ingredients = $category->ingredients;
```

This will give you a Collection with all the ingredients of this category.

You could also use this for every category.

```
$categories = Category::all(); //Get all categories
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $ingredients = $category->ingredients; //Get all ingredients
}
```

Extra:

Note that i'm not using the () after ingredients, this has to do with the mysql queries that are executed (Without () it will look if it has results (if yes it will use these of no it will query your database and then use the results)).

Comment: Thanks sir. i understand very much.